# Root access without authentication with OpenSSH server

Tags: server, ssh, login, password, authentication

I have allowed SSH root login with SSH-key authentication to a Ubuntu Server 16.04. This is set with option `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. If I don't set root password at all and some other administrator sets `PermitRootLogin yes`, is it possible somehow to login without any password or SSH-keys?

And is it generally possible to configure OpenSSH server to accept root login without any authentication?

Comment: Two things: SSH's `PermitEmptyPasswords` and PAM's `pam_unix.so` usually having `null_ok_secure` might still prevent that. But of course, the other administrator can change those. And undo any other changes you might do, since they have complete administrative privileges as well.

Comment: Oh yeah there's option `PermitEmptyPasswords`. I was just thinking that some administrator could change `prohibit-password` to `yes` to test something fast and open the server for all world accidentally.

But just with the two things you mentioned, one would really need to try to allow access for the whole world. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the default configuration is pretty good (`PermitRootLogin without-password` - this is the first I'm hearing of `prohibit-password`). You have to actively change configuration just to get a default Ubuntu SSH server to accept passwords for root.

Comment: I'm quite sure `prohibit-password` is now the default option at least in Ubuntu Server 16.04 installations. And in my mind `prohibit-password` describes the option and it effects better.

_sshd_config(5): PermitRootLogin now accepts an argument of 'prohibit-password' as a less-ambiguous synonym of 'without-password'._ Source:
[https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0)

Comment: ah, an OpenSSH 7 thing. They're synonyms, so, in any case, the default is sane